# Cloud SQL TLS Cypher support

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am looking to get a list of the support or configurable TLS Cypher that can be use with GCP MySQL 8.x engine. (From GCP UI)

On the configuration page, there is no options to specify, enable or even disable some desired or undesired ones.

Are there any policies I need to change at the top level of the project or there is just no option at all.

It seem to only support TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (or that I was able to connect using)
at the moment.
Not that it's not a fine solution, just that corpo. wise, this is not a prefered cypher.

Comment: Neither there are ''flags'' to configured with the name containing TLS or CYPHER

Comment: 1) Why are you concerned with `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`?  What is your preferred cipher? 2) Cloud SQL does not support SSL policies. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-policies-concepts

Comment: Like stated, it is not a ''prefered corporate'' cypher. Not a personal choice ;-) IMO, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @yield, did the comment above answer your question? If so, please post it as an answer so that it would be helpful to community members with similar questions.

Comment: No it does not. I will update soon as I am testing now.

Comment: Sorry. Short on time. I will post soon. I have not forgot